# Using XLSX NPM package not showing values from array

Tags: javascript, typescript, xlsx

I have an object like this:

```
{
  property1: [
    { 
      date: Date,
      values: {
        prop1: xyz,
        prop2: xyz,
        prop3: xyz
     }
   }
 ],
 property2: {
   id: 245232,
   description: "My awesome description"
 }
}
```

In my Excel Service, and having imported XLSX package, I have the following code.

```
public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
}
```

When I call the excel service, I will pass in my array of `Ojbect.property1` (which is an array of other objs).

The output of the excel file is just the date field of each object inside the property1 array. Although I want the date field to be column on1, values.prop1 to be column 2, values.prop2 to be column 3....

Can anyone shed light on why those other columns aren't populating from the values object?

Comment: I would try to flatten the content of those object, to have keys and values at the same level. I mean, `prop1`, `prop2` and so on, at the same level of `date`

Comment: that's a good idea. I can try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, based on [this](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs#array-of-objects-input) part of the documentation, it seems you need to flatten the object to make it work.
Check out its example:

```js
var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet([
  { S:1, h:2, e:3, e_1:4, t:5, J:6, S_1:7 },
  { S:2, h:3, e:4, e_1:5, t:6, J:7, S_1:8 }
], {header:["S","h","e","e_1","t","J","S_1"]});
```

Have in mind the order of the columns is based on `Object.keys()`.

Hope this helps. :fingers_crossed:

Comment: yup. worked fine after I created a new class and reconstructed a new obj and array off the returned data and passed that into the excel service. Thanks!